# mysql stored procedure glitching

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to limit table record to 25. after I just delete everything (in the future will modify it to delete just oldest rows)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE p1 () delete FROM tests;//

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
BEFORE INSERT
ON tests
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt FROM tests;
  IF @cnt >= 25 THEN
    CALL p1();
  END IF;
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

, but I am getting error: 
    Can't update table 'tests' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

So I can not add any more fields.

Comment: Surely we can , together, think of a slightly more descriptive title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL trigger FAQ sais that you cannot modify the table that calls the trigger.

But you can set up a cron job, or `CREATE EVENT` in MySQL that cleans the table at regular intervals. (CREATE EVENT needs the PROCESS privilege, and a running event_scheduler. The event_scheduler is turned off by default: it can be turned on from SQL console, but the MySQL config must be modified to ensure that it starts when MySQL restarts.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't update or delete from the same table which invoked the trigger.
But you can work around this by creating another table, for example `tests2` and instead of inserting into `tests` just insert into `tests2`, and have the trigger insert the `NEW.` values into tests, then you can count from tests and delete from tests like how you want it.
see this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f94ea/1/0)
The problem with this is then `tests2` gets filled up with Inserted data So you might have to manually delete from tests2.